# Order in Scala set

Tags: scala, set

I noticed, when Scala Set has less than 5 elements, it maintains order. But it doesn't maintain order after that. Just curious to know the reason behind it.

Note - I am not depending on the order of elements in a Set. This is an observation and curious to know if this is a correct observation and how is this happening.
Code example:

```
  val s= Set(4,3,1)
  println(s)
  val s1= Set(4,3,1,2)
  println(s1)
  val s2= Set(4,3,1,2,5)
  println(s2)
```

Output:

```
Set(4, 3, 1)
Set(4, 3, 1, 2)
Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Sets are unordered collection. The fact that you see them in order until the first four is juts a an implementation detail and you may even consider that a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Scala 2.13 implementation for immutable Set](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala) it appears the code has special case class implementations for sets up to size 4.